# Настройка .htaccess-файла

Tags: url, .htaccess, php

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема. Пишу сайт на голом php, без использования framework'ов, и хотелось бы немного перезаписать url'ки. Сейчас выглядит все примерно так:

```
http://--------.kz/?page=article&id=7
```

А хочется, перезаписать на

```
http://--------.kz/article/7
```

или название статьи, если возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^article/([0-9A-Za-z_-]+)\.html /?page=article&id=$1 [L]`

В принципе перезаписал все. ;)

Спасибо!